# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, sqlexception

I have a java web application that is running on jetty that connects to SQL server local database (I'm using hibernate). Both the application and the database are in the SAME PC. Everything runs smoothly until I disable the network adapter or unplug the Ethernet wire, at this moment I cannot access my web app and getting this (among other nested exceptions) exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed. 
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.checkOpen(ConnectionJDBC2.java:1713)  
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.setAutoCommit(ConnectionJDBC2.java:2223)  
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.checkTransaction (BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:429)  
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransaction (WrappedConnection.java:525)  
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection.commit(WrappedConnection.java:333)  
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commitAndResetAutoCommit (JDBCTransaction.java:170)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:146)  
... 51 more
```

Any thoughts?

P.S: If you need further info please tell me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure even the loopback adapter will respond to a network down event caused by the network adapter being disabled, or the wire being pulled from the card.  Even though your not physically going out over the network, the adapters still have to respond to catastrophic events.  Have you tried setting the connection up using named pipes?  jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/dbname;networkProtocol=namedpipes

Comment: Sorry for the delay... Never used pipes in windows(and java) yet. Could you be a bit more specific on its usage, please?